# Push not working using client code Parse.com IOS

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, client

Im not receiving the push on my device using the push client code below on other IOS device.

```
        PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];

        NSString *to = [[[AppDelegate appDelegate].sendTo componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"] firstObject];

        [push setChannel:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"z%@",to]];

        [push setMessage:@"dscxvx"];

        [push sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * __nullable error) {

            if (succeeded) {

                NSLog(@"succeeded");

            }

            NSLog(@"error==%@",error.localizedDescription);

        }];
```

Below are some observations that i feel are correct so that i should receive a push but unfortunately it doesnt.

1) I have enabled the client key in parse website(settings push).

2) The channels are set in core for both the IOS device along with the device tokens

3) I have cross checked the channel name set in my IOS code with the one set in parse website core section.

4) When check the push section in parse web site it shows the push as sent to 0 devices.

5) Also The push works when i send it from parse website to all devices and by rest api too using postman extension for chrome.

6) In the above code "succeeded" is printed in console and error is Null.That shows push is sent but was never delivered to any device.

Only sending the push through client code doesn't work for me.
Please help.

Comment: Have you enabled your app's Bundle ID to handle push notifications?  If you have, have you also uploaded the APNS push certificates to Parse?  Because if you answer is to any of these questions is 'no', please refer to Parse's docs for info on how to properly set up iOS push notifications.

Comment: yes i have enabled the bundle id for push in development mode.APNS p12 uploaded to parse too.Please check 5) that make sure teh above things are done correctly.

Comment: Its working now...Issue was the channel name had a letter with capitals and i was send push to a channel with all small letters.